# How to unregister my app from Visual Studio 2013 Office 365 API connected services

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory

When using Office 365 API on our web site we just need to create an AD app using Visual Studio Connected Services. In connected services window we can first register app by click on register app link. If I want to create a new app or remove the connectivity with office 365 how do we do that.
How to unregister my app from Visual Studio 2013 Office 365 API connected services.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove the link in the Visual Studio project, you can delete the `ida:ClientID` and `ida:Password` keys from your `web.config` file.

If you want to revoke the app's client ID altogether, logon to the Azure Management Portal and delete the app.